# Preamble before Do Carmo's proof of the Cauchy-Crofton Formula

Tags: differential-geometry

On page $42$ of Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* he defines a rigid motion in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a map $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) \rightarrow (x,y)$ as Equation $(6)$ given by:

$$x = a + \bar{x}\cos(\phi)- \bar{y}\sin(\phi)$$
$$y = b + \bar{x}\sin(\phi)+ \bar{y}\cos(\phi)$$

i.e., a rotation about the origin followed by a translation.

On page $44$ he then writes that Equation $(6)$ maps the line $x \cos (\theta) + y \sin (\theta) = p$ (for constants $\theta$ and $p$) into the line

$$ \bar{x} \cos (\theta - \phi) + \bar{y} \sin(\theta - \phi) = p - a \cos(\theta) - b \sin (\theta)$$

I'm a bit confused about this last equation. Seems to me that for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $x \cos (\theta) + y \sin (\theta) = p$, that

$$F(x \cos(\theta), y \sin (\theta))$$

$$= (a + x \cos (\theta) \cos (\phi) - y \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi),
b + x \sin(\theta) \sin (\phi) + y \sin(\theta) \cos (\phi))$$
Not sure why either the RHS or LHS of the following equation satisfies the line that $F$ maps $x \cos(\theta) + y \sin (\theta)$ onto: $$ \bar{x} \cos (\theta - \phi) + \bar{y} \sin(\theta - \phi) = p - a \cos(\theta) - b \sin (\theta)$$  Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Hint: [Linear Combinatons of Sine and Cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) or better [Product To Sum and Sum To Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

Comment: I think you should have $y=b+\bar{x}\sin\phi+\bar{y}\cos\phi$ instead of both sines.  Then the line $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=p$ is related by your $F$ (or rather, the inverse of it) to the line $(a+\bar{x}\cos\phi-\bar{y}\sin\phi)\cos\theta+(b+\bar{x}\sin\phi+\bar{y}\cos\phi)\sin\theta=p$.

Comment: @user10354138 typo corrected, and yes I thought it might be the inverse of $F$.

Comment: @user10354138 posted my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Do Carmo means that the points $\{(x,y)\}$ on the line satisfy $(x,y) = (a + \bar{x}\cos(\phi)- \bar{y}\sin(\phi), b + \bar{x}\sin(\phi)+ \bar{y}\cos(\phi)) = F(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$, i.e. the points on the line in question are the image of a rigid transform acting on another line $\{(\bar{x}, \bar{y}) \}$ (with a bit of abuse of notation here) and $F^{-1}(\{x,y\}) = (\{\bar{x}, \bar{y}\})$

If $(x,y)$ satisfies $x \cos(\theta) + y \sin (\theta) = p$, then
$(a + \bar{x}\cos(\phi)- \bar{y}\sin(\phi)) \cos (\theta) + (b+\bar{x}\sin(\phi)+ \bar{y}\cos(\phi)) \sin (\theta) = p$, then since

$$ \cos (\theta-\phi) = \cos(\theta)\cos(\phi) + \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$
and
$$ \sin (\theta-\phi) = \sin(\theta)\cos(\phi) - \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$

then

$$ \bar{x} \cos (\theta - \phi) + \bar{y} \sin(\theta - \phi) = p - a \cos(\theta) - b \sin (\theta)$$